# Error 401 Unauthoridced al hacer login con Springsecurity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Estoy intenyando hacer un API securizada con SpringBoot, pero al hacer login me devuelve 401 Unauthorized.

Tengo la clase SecurityConfig de la siguiente forma:

```
package com.BookExchange.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT alias, password, enabled FROM users WHERE alias=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT alias, role FROM user_roles WHERE alias=?")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/AppName/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/AppName/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return  new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

El [postman](/questions/tagged/postman) estoy lanzando una petición POST a la url

```
http://localhost:8080/AppName/login
```

con el body:

```
{
    "alias": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}
```

Por favor, ¿alguna idea de que puede pasar? El usuario `admin :: admin` si existe en base de datos y la aplicación no arroja ninguna traza de log.

Mil gracias de antemano.